# php regular expression problems

Tags: php, preg-match

have a problem with validating regular expressions using php.

I have an html form posted below that asks for phone number, license plate, street address, birthday and social insurance number. **( I am only concerned with getting the phone number and street to work correctly for now)**

**I need to use the preg_match function to adhere to the following criteria for phone numbers:**

phone number – 7 digits or 10 digits

◦7 digits: the first three digits are one group, and may be separated from the final four digits with a dash, one or more spaces, or nothing at all

◦10 digits: the first three digits, second three digits, and final four digits are three distinct groups and each group may be separated from its neighboring group by nothing, a dash, or one-or-more spaces, or brackets

◦eg. all of these are valid
▪(604)123-4567 but not 604)123-4567 and not (604123-4567
▪6041234567
▪1234567
▪123-4567
▪123 4567
▪604-123-4567
▪604 123 4567
▪604 1234567
▪604123 456

**I need to use the preg_match function to adhere to the following criteria for phone numbers:**

Street Address – three to five number address followed by a string, must end with the word "Street"
◦eg. these are valid
▪123 Main Street
▪8888 Oak Street
▪55555 Dunsmuir Street

**the code so far for lab11.html and lab11.php**
**lab11.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 11</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="lab11.php" method="POST">
<input  type="text" name="phoneNumber"placeholder="Phone Number" style="font-size: 15pt">
<br>
<input  type="text"name="licensePlate"placeholder="License Plate" style="font-size: 15pt">
<br>
<input  type="text" name="streetAddress" placeholder="Street Address" style="font-size: 15pt">
<br>
<input  type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday" style="font-size: 15pt">
<br>
<input  type="text" name="socialInsuranceNumber" placeholder="Social Insurance Number" style="font-size: 15pt">
<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

lab11.php

```
<?php
    // Get phone number, license plate, street address, birthday and 
    // social insurance number entered from lab11.html form
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
        echo "Your phone number is " . $phoneNumber;
        echo "<br>";
    $licensePlate = $_POST['licensePlate'];
        echo "Your License Plate Number is " . $licensePlate;
        echo "<br>";
    $streetAddress = $_POST['streetAddress'];
        echo "Your Street Address is " . $streetAddress;
        echo "<br>";
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
        echo "Your Birthday is " . $birthday;
        echo "<br>";
    $socialInsuranceNumber = $_POST['socialInsuranceNumber'];
        echo "Your Social Insurance Number is " . $socialInsuranceNumber;

    echo "<br>";

    // Validate regular expression for phone number entered
    if (preg_match("/^\(.[0-9]{3}[0-9]$/", $phoneNumber)) {
        echo "Your phone is correct.";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Your password is wrong.";
    }
    // Validate regular expression for license plate entered
    if (preg_match("/{3,5}.String$/", $streetAddress)) {
        echo "Your plate is correct.";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Your plate is wrong.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex for the phone number:

```
^(\([\d]{3}\)|[\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?([\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?[\d]{3}(-|\s*)?[\d]{4}$
```

and for the addresses:

```
^([\d]{3,5})\s+[a-zA-Z'"\s]+\s*Street$ - you can add `i` modifier for case insensitive
```

`[a-zA-Z'"\s]` - only given letters + '" and white space - for street name. Depending on your needs you can modify it

Comment: This will accept `++++_______Street` as a valid address! and `+++++++++++++` as a valid phone number

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I fixed the mistake.